# Google Glass sensors and API levels

Tags: android, google-glass, android-sensors, google-gdk

The following paragraph is a note found in the GDK references for Google Glass.
But I'm not sure exactly what it means. Can anyone explain to me what this paragraph
is trying explain?

Note: The Glass platform is based on Android 4.4 (API Level 19), but does not support the sensor features of that platform level or Android 4.3 (API Level 18). API features for sensors is frozen at Android 4.2 (API Level 17) for the aforementioned sensors that are supported.

Answer (score 2):

Glass plateform is 4.4 uses API 19 you can use all android features but in case you want to use sensors you need to see API lvl 17 reference to know what you can and can't use
so you cant use
    TYPE_SIGNIFICANT_MOTION 
    TYPE_STEP_COUNTER
    TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR
        getFifoMaxEventCount()
        getFifoReservedEventCount()
        ...
visit [Android developper reference for more details](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html)